# Map collection of timespan with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an object that contains a collection of `TimeSpan` like `Note.Reminders`, where reminders is `List<TimeSpan>`. How to I map this using [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/)?

Currently I have mapped it as `m.HasMany(c=>c.Reminders).Access.CamelCaseField()`.

But it complains that it can not find a mapping for type `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HasMany` maps associations to other entities. `TimeSpan`s are values, not entities. Therefore you should use `Map(c=>c.Reminders);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that the type in your database to store those timestamps is an Int64.